# Event Streams vs TaskRouter callbacks

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I have an application that uses Twilio Conference. My use-case is to parse the events and store them in a datastore like Redis.

Currently I'm using [TaskRouter callback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/event/reference) to get events on my backend. Recently, I've came across Twilio [Event Stream](https://www.twilio.com/docs/events/webhook-quickstart#create-a-sink-instance).

Now I'm confused when to use which.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at [this page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/events/faq) of the docs, which says:

> The type of events and data we’ll be supporting within Event Streams are similar to the events that Twilio sends via informational webhooks today. However, existing webhooks have a few shortcomings. First, HTTP falls short as a transport when customers require at-least-once delivery of their data. If a webhook fails for any reason — e.g., an error within Twilio or an error from the customer’s server — then that event is lost and can’t be sent again. Additionally, there is no backpressure mechanism built into HTTP that prevents customer servers from being overwhelmed by unanticipated traffic volume.

Basically, Event Streams is a more robust product.